# what is the diference in Push Notification of iOS 4, iOS 5 and iOS 6?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Hi I am totally new to apple ios. I read and searched lots of artical about the push notification but i didn't find any thing much regarding the new updation from io4 to ios 6 for APNS. Can any one provide me proper information how APNS works on ios4 to ios 6? Is there any implementation changes?

Also i know that apple changes the way the PN appears in iOS 4 and iOS 5 like when PN appears ios 5 can show it without unlocking the device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no, there is no change in implementation.

Comment: While this may be the correct answer, I would encourage you to elaborate, as from code - yes, there are no differences, but to a user there is. NC was a huge addition to the OS, and while it doesn't mean much to a dev, it still must be considered.

Comment: There is zero code difference though.  The way you process notifications opened outside the app remains the same before and after notification center arrived.

Answer (score 0):

there is no difference in the code.
   You can either use the same code for notifications whatever the ios version you are using.